# How to split a string column in GRAFANA (INFLUXDB)

Tags: split, grafana, influxdb

I would like to visualize with GRAFANA some sensor data that I collect with INFLUXDB. The problem is that I collect all sensor data (7 values) as a string. The values are separated by commas, and I want to split them into seven different integers.
[GRAFANA_INFLUXDB_string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppMu3.png)

Comment: Finally, I have used a split function to split the string value into integers and after that, I can post them into influx as integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function toHexString(bytes) {
return bytes.map(function(byte) {
    return ("00" + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2)
  }).join('')
```

}

```
function Decode(fPort, bytes) {

var tohex = toHexString(bytes);
var toascii = hex_to_ascii(tohex);
var a = toascii.slice(0).split(',');
var myObj = {};
{
myObj.one = a[0];
myObj.two = parseInt(a[1])/100;
myObj.three = parseInt(a[2])/100;
myObj.four = parseInt(a[3])/10;
myObj.five = parseInt(a[4]);
myObj.six = parseInt(a[5])/10;
myObj.seven = parseInt(a[6])/10;
}
return {"mydata": myObj};
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To conclude, I have a LoRa node which sends encoded values (base64) to a chirpstack server through a LoRa gateway. In the chirpstack server I use a function to decode the receipted values, in order to save them into an Influx database and finally visualize them in a grafana dashboard. The problem was that values had to be numbers, so I changed the decode function to convert a string into separated values.